# 301 Redirect Match

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Good day guys,

Please how do I create a 301 redirect for these pages which are appearing as 404 crawl errors in Google Webmaster Tool? There are like 30 of them now

http://www.patchworkoftips.com/install-google-play-store-unsupported-android-phones/1624/&sa=U&ved=0CEIQFjAHahUKEwjuu67BvorIAhVlHKYKHWtPB9k&usg=AFQjCNF0NIVDHik0JcOeQkfXa3yP3190OQ

http://www.patchworkoftips.com/install-google-play-store-unsupported-android-phones/1624/&sa=U&ved=0CEwQFjAJahUKEwiAscDn6IbHAhXkqqYKHakyDvc&usg=AFQjCNF0NIVDHik0JcOeQkfXa3yP3190OQ

http://www.patchworkoftips.com/install-google-play-store-unsupported-android-phones/1624/&sa=U&ved=0CE0QFjAJahUKEwjAzLKkkZXHAhUHIaYKHQj1C1U&usg=AFQjCNF0NIVDHik0JcOeQkfXa3yP3190OQ

I want them all redirecting to the actual page http://www.patchworkoftips.com/install-google-play-store-unsupported-android-phones/1624/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll more than likely need a generic handler for this - I naturally assume that more than one page is being hit here.

Add the following under `RewriteEngine On`:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)&sa=.+&ved=.+&usg=.+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [R=302,L]
```

To make the redirect 'permanent', change 302 to 301.